# Can Get Location, but not heading

Tags: ios, swift, core-location

I'm only using the simulator currently, but I'm having trouble with CoreLocation in swift on the iOS simulator. I get position updates printed by this code, but never heading. I don't want course, I'm trying to make a compass type app that will show a bearing to a target.

```
class CompassViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    var lm:CLLocationManager = CLLocationManager()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        print ("view did load")

        lm.delegate = self;
        lm.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        lm.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        lm.startUpdatingLocation()
        lm.startUpdatingHeading()

    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        var locValue:CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location!.coordinate
        var course = manager.location!.course
               print("locations = \(locations)")
    }

    func headingManger(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateHeading: [CLHeading]) {
        var heading = manager.heading?.magneticHeading
        print("heading = \(heading)")
    }

}
```

I've tried a few combinations of this. I tried doing one function that handled both location and heading, but that didn't get any data printing at all. I also tried just having the headingManager function, but nothing was printed. This current code as above will print the location, but not the heading.

How can I get heading to work as well?

Comment: Getting a heading requires a device with a compass, of which the simulator does not have.

Comment: So is the only way to test apps with compass actually on the device?

Comment: Yes, you'll need a device with a built-in compass.

Comment: Ok so now I'm running this same code on my iPhone via X Code and I still don't get compass heading. My location is output but not compass heading.

Answer (score 6):

Compass is not in the list of the hardware interactions supported by the simulator and CLLocationManager headingAvailable reports it's not available on the simulator.

Also, in this doc:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html

Some location services require the presence of specific hardware on the given device. For example, heading information is available only for devices that contain a hardware compass. This class defines several methods that you can use to determine which services are currently available.
Specifically CLLocationManager has this class property to check if the compass is available:

- (BOOL)headingAvailable
  If I run this under the simulator:

print("headingAvailable: (Int(CLLocationManager.headingAvailable()))")
Outputs:

2011-11-08 22:38:26.873 Craplet[39975:b603] headingAvailable: 0

Comment: Ok I'm now running this same code on my phone, but still only get location not heading.

Comment: you need to setup the Compass feature in phone then try this code.. it will work

Comment: How do you do that?

Comment: There are bunch of example you can try official apple eg.
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/GettingHeadings/GettingHeadings.html

Answer (score 0):

David,

I was refered to your question, which wasn't the answer. This was...

[didUpdateHeading heading never called under iOS 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46488655/didupdateheading-heading-never-called-under-ios-11/46489849#46489849)

Don't know if your running iOS 11, the beta was around in June I suspect, but certainly not released until September 2017, but maybe this hopes.