# didUpdateHeading heading never called under iOS 11

Tags: ios, swift, compass

Using XCode Version 9.0 (9A235) but with Swift 3.x

My app Works ok on iOS 10.x didUpdateHeading called looks good, but under iOS 11.x the same app crashes cause didUpdateHeading never gets called.

Did I miss some permission change to use the compass or something in IOS 11.x

Comment: Please refer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44479865/can-get-location-but-not-heading

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the answer in WWDC 2017.

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/713/

Two things.

I was asking for authorizationAlways which I wasn't being granted in iOS 11.x and I needed to add all four of these keys.

```
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>Blah Blah</string>
<key>NSLocationUsageDescription</key>
<string>Blah Blah</string>
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>Blah Blah</string>
```

And

```
<key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>This one is new</string>
```

Now it works!!

Answer (score 0):

Ironically just found myself back and my answer, two years later. Bewarned I came here cause there have been some drastic changes to CoreLocation authorisations. See the WWDC https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/705/ for more details.